# Express body-parser: req.body returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I've got a simple Express server that uses the `body-parser` module to access POST-parameters. The app looks like this:

### /index.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const apiRouter = require('./api/routes.js');


// Set our port for the server application
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


// Register the routes for the /api prefix
app.use('/api', apiRouter);


// Start server
app.listen(port);
console.log('The server is running on port ' + port);
```

### /api/routes.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Configure app to use bodyParser(). This will let us get the data from a POST
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());


// START ROUTES

router.post('/devices', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // Returns {}
  res.json(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that the `req.body` object is empty (**Always** returns an empty object `{}`). Since I already loaded the `body-parser` middleware I have no idea what else I can try. I hope you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the app Postman for testing. It appeared that it sent the POST data as `form-data` instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`. After changing this setting the data showed up.